# How to write Linux command-line app in Kotlin script to make a machine a wifi direct group owner then listen on a port on the wifi direct interface?

Tags: linux, kotlin, wifi-direct

I need to write a simple Kotlin script or command-line app to make the Linux machine it's running on a wifi direct group owner, then listen on a port on the wifi direct interface for incoming wifi direct group member connections.  Once the connection is established, the server & client can go about exchanging data using my protocol.

I'm having a heck of a time finding docs and/or examples for this.  Can anyone point me to a Kotlin or Java library for wifi direct, or, better, a sample Kotlin or Java app that establishes the machine as a wifi direct group owner?